Authenticated User "Unable to tunnel through Proxy..."
I have a connection between a Dev Box and a Full Box instance. I set up this way:
Fullbox - Connected App
Dev Box
--> Named Credentials Uses Auth provider with login flow on save.
--> Auth. Provider (Consumer Key & Secret)
I'm successfully authenticated, but I cannot use the namedCredentials in API calls. It's failing and giving the following error:
Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error"
Here is the code that returned that error:
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest(); 
req.setEndpoint('callout:myCreds/services/data/v60.0/limits');
req.setMethod('GET');
Http http = new HTTP(); 
HttpResponse resp = http.send(req); 
String httpResponse = resp.getBody();

I'm not sure why, as this has worked in the past, but it appears there were some updates to named credentials since I last used it.
I've also confirmed that I can hit the target Sandbox with Postman. The only thing that I haven't tried is whitelisting all of the Salesforce IP addresses within the Fullbox, but this seems odd that I would have to do this, since its Salesforce <-> Salesforce.
Any help, would be great.
Addtional Actions
I also whitelisted the IP addresses here just to see if it would work. But it did not: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000384438&type=1

did you ever figure this out? having a similar issue

It's been awhile, but I believe it had to do with our network and I had to go through our Network/Security teams to help me out.
